# Getting error while installing ruby-saml(1.3.0) in rails 2.3.2 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, saml, saml-2.0

I am getting below error while installing ruby-saml(1.3.0) in my application(ruby 1.8.7,rails 2.3.2).

> Fetching: ruby-saml-1.3.0.gem (100%) ERROR:  Error installing
>   ruby-saml: mini_portile2 requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.

In gem list i can see the ruby-saml gem

```
gem li ruby-saml
```

> ** LOCAL GEMS **
>
> ruby-saml (1.3.0)

I have installed **mini_portile (0.6.2)**, **nokogiri (1.5.10)**

I want to install ruby-saml(1.3.0) in ruby 1.8.7 because there are multiple functions(OneLogin::RubySaml::SloLogoutresponse,OneLogin::RubySaml::SloLogoutrequest) for idp initiated SLO, which are not in ruby-saml(0.7.2).

Question

1. Why i am getting above error?
2. Is there any problem without mini_portile2?
3. Is there any other way to install ruby-saml(1.3.0) in ruby 1.8.7?

Please help

Comment: Anyone know about this, why I am getting above error ?

Answer (score 0):

Ruby-saml uses Nokogiri as a dependency, which requires updated mini_portile (mini_portile_**2**), but you should check if tips form [here](https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml#installation-on-ruby-187). It might help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I already installed nokogiri (1.5.10) and mini_portile (0.6.2) gem still, I am getting  the same error(ERROR: Error installing ruby-saml:,mini_portile2 requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.). Are there any other dependencies?

Comment: There was a mistake in my answer, but nie it's correct. It's all about that little '2' on the end. You have installed old mini_portile, but you need updated version: mini_portile_2.

Comment: I can't update mini_portile in my app (ruby 1.8.7) because updated version of mini_portile requires ruby 1.9 +. DO we have any other option to fix this issue?